# Why is this 'obviously' positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Here is a snapshot from a book I am studying. I learned all about positive semi-definiteness, and in fact I know that this matrix they are showing is in fact PSD.

[image]

What I do not know is how they conclude it is PSD from the last part of the equation, when they factor the matrix into a vector times its transpose.

How is it 'obvious' from here that this is PSD?

Again, I know how to show the PSDness of this matrix, but I am not clear how/why they concluded the same thing, using the vector times vector^T in the end.

Thanks.

Comment: When $A = v\cdot v^T$, then $x^TAx = (x^T v)\cdot (v^T x)= (x^Tv)^2 \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah! Makes perfect sense. So actually it doesnt even matter what values $x$ takes right? ($y$ has to be > 0, but apart from this restriction, $x$ can be anything it seems?)

Comment: Whatever $v$ is, the matrix $v\cdot v^T$ is positive semidefinite, since then $x^TAx$ is a square.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, that makes sense. The restriction on $y \in R_{++}$ comes from the $\frac{2}{y^3}$ outside, but yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and $A=aa^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, as in the case of your matrix.

Clearly, $A$ is symmetric, as $A^T= (aa^T)^T=(a^T)^Ta^T=aa^T=A$.

$A$ is positive definite because of the fact that $(x,Ax)\ge 0$, for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$. 
Indeed
$$
(x,Ax)=x^TAx=x^Taa^Tx=(x^Ta)(a^Tx)=(x^Ta)^2\ge 0.
$$

Note that $x^Ta$ is nothing but the inner product of $x$ and $a$.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the observation that any matrix of the form $A = B^T B$ is automatically positive semi definite and is positive definite if $B$ has linearly independent columns(equivalently $B^T$ has linearly independent rows).

Proof: Let $x$ be any vector of the right dimension, then
$$
x^T A x= x^T B^T B x = y^T y \ge 0 ~~~\text{where $y=B x$}
$$
This shows that $A$ is semi definite. It will be definite if $y=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ which is equivalent to requiring $B$ to have linearly independent columns.

Comment: A nice perspective to add to the others. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 1):

**Another perspective on this:** suppose $A$ has the form $A = uu^T$ for some vector $u$.  Then for any real vector $v$, we have
$$
Av = uu^Tv = u(u^Tv) = (u\cdot v)u 
$$
Where $u\cdot v$ represents a dot-product.

So, note that $Av$ will be $0$ if $v$ is perpendicular to $u$, and $Au = (u\cdot u)u$.  This determines all eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of $A$.  Since all eigenvectors are non-negative, we conclude $A$ is PSD.

Moreover, it's probably good to know the following:

> An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a rank-$k$ PSD matrix if and only if it can be expressed in the form $A = BB^T$ for some $n \times k$ matrix $B$.

Comment: Interesting Omononomnomnonom that makes sense, echoing @Daniel Fischer's comment. Thanks!

Comment: Your last comment reminds me on Non-Negative-Matrix factorization, where a matrix $A$ is indeed split into this form. I wonder if they 'care' about rank-k norms in NMF.

Answer (score 0):

I will just throw in another perspective. For a given matrix, if all the principle minors are non-negative, then the matrix is positive semi-definite. (Note: if you want positive definiteness, then you need to check only the leading principle minors.)

For the 2-by-2 matrix, this is easy to check. Here the principle minors are $x^2$, $y^2$, and $x^2 y^2 - x^2 y^2 = 0$. Clearly, $x^2$ and $y^2$ will always be positive, while the last one is zero. Hence the matrix is positive semi-definite.