# Proof that $x x^T$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, outer-product

For a generic vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it is clear the outer product $xx^T$ is a symmetric matrix.

But how can we prove that this is a positive semidefinite as well?

The matrix $X:=xx^T$ is given by the elements $x_{ij} = x_ix_j$.

A reference or answer would be great.

Comment: Can you simplify $a^T (x x^T) a $? Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678861/42969.

Comment: If you know of the equivalence of positive semidefiniteness and non-negative eigenvalues, then you can look at the eigenvalues of $X$.

Comment: @MartinR gave you a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a column vector $\in\Bbb R^n$ so, since $Y\cdot x$ is a scalar,
$$Y^TXY = Y^Txx^TY = (x^TY)^T(x^TY)\implies Y\cdot XY = (x^TY)^2 \geq 0.$$